# Updating rows conditionally with a gapless ascending value

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, gaps-and-islands

A user has a table they would like to update.  Depending on the data in other columns they want a particular column to be updated with an ascending value starting from 1 that is gap-less.  The rows that will not contain this ascending value also need to be updated.  Is there a way to do this with a single UPDATE statement?

Create sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS (
   SELECT CHR(ASCII('a')+rownum-1) letter, rownum Number1, 0 Number2 
   FROM dual connect by rownum<=7);
```

Update statement that assigns an ascending rownum, but it isn't gap-less:

```
UPDATE t1 SET Letter=’x’, 
   Number2 = DECODE(letter,’a’,rownum,’d’,rownum,’e’,rownum,NULL);
```

Using a sequence returns the same results:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s1;
UPDATE t1 SET letter=’x’, 
   number2 = DECODE(letter,’a’,s1.nextval,’d’, s1.nextval,’e’, s1.nextval,NULL);
```

The data should look like this when complete:

```
L    NUMBER1    NUMBER2
- ---------- ----------
x          1          1
x          2
x          3
x          4          2
x          5          3
x          6
x          7
```

I'm not looking for a trick applicable only to my specific test case, but a general solution to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this [discussion on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8491662046178) about the way expressions are evaluated. The `decode` function does perform short-circuit in most cases: right-side expressions are not evaluated if a condition on the left is evaluated to `true`. Sequence are special however, they are evaluated for all lines in all cases.

The easiest workaround is to use a function that calls the sequence:

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq;

Sequence created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f RETURN NUMBER
  2  AS
  3     l_result NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT seq.nextval INTO l_result FROM dual;
  6     RETURN l_result;
  7  END;
  8  /

Function created

SQL> UPDATE t1 SET letter='x',
  2     number2 = DECODE(letter,'a',f,'d', f,'e', f,NULL);

7 rows updated

SQL> select * from t1;

LETTER    NUMBER1    NUMBER2
------ ---------- ----------
x               1          1
x               2 
x               3 
x               4          2
x               5          3
x               6 
x               7 

7 rows selected
```

As you can see the function is evaluated only when the DECODE expression requires it.

---

You can work a pure SQL solution in most cases. If we assume that the table has a PK (I'll take `number1`), this self-join SQL solution would work:

```
SQL> UPDATE t1 t1_out
  2     SET letter  = 'x',
  3         number2 = CASE WHEN letter IN ('a', 'd', 'e') --
  4                        THEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
  5                                FROM t1 t1_in
  6                               WHERE letter IN ('a', 'd', 'e')
  7                                 AND t1_in.number1 <= t1_out.number1)
  8                   END;

7 rows updated

SQL> select * from t1;

LETTER    NUMBER1    NUMBER2
------ ---------- ----------
x               1          1
x               2 
x               3 
x               4          2
x               5          3
x               6 
x               7 

7 rows selected
```

You have probably tried an analytics solution. It is possible to write a query that will return the appropriate result set but update and analytics don't work very well together (analytics tend to produce non-updatable views).

Comment: +1 Excellent solutions.  I'll post mine, but depending on the situation either of yours is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an Update statement, but it does meet the other requirements of the question.

```
MERGE INTO t1 b
USING (SELECT letter, number1, number2, 
   Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY 
      DECODE(letter,'a',1,'d',1,'e',1,0) ORDER BY number1) SectionRow FROM t1) a 
ON (a.number1 = b.number1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET b.letter='x', 
   b.number2 = 
      DECODE(a.letter,'a',SectionRow,'d',SectionRow,'e',SectionRow,NULL);
```